# Change TLS version to 1.2 in atom component in apachecamel

Tags: java, apache-camel

We are using atom component in apache-camel to consume some atom events from some api, but that api is now asking us to change TLS version to TSLv1.2, I am not getting where to do those changes can some help me how to do...

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to upgrade to Java 8, as it uses TLS 1.2 as default. Otherwise, include the following on the command line when you run the application:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

This parameter (`https.protocols`) tells the JVM which protocol version(s) should be used during HTTPS connections.

If you want to support both 1.1 and 1.2:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```